# How strong is C-3PO?

Tags: star-wars

In *A New Hope* we see 3PO putting the corpses of Jawas on the fire, this is the only instance I can think were we see him doing a physically demanding task.

[image: Here we see 3PO and the recently carried jawas]

Is there anything to say how is strength compares to, say a Human?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Probably a little weaker than a human

We don’t really know how strong C-3PO is. His uselessness in combat suggests that, unlike some droids, he likely does not have strength far in excess of that of a human.

In the scene mentioned in the question, C-3PO appears to be strong enough to lift Jawa corpses. However, Jawas are a lot smaller than humans.

He’s certainly strong enough to carry a fairly large gun, and deal with its recoil, as seen in the scene in which C-3PO’s head is transplanted to a battle droid:

[image]

On the other hand, C-3PO does not appear to be strong enough to lift Padme and carry her to her ship on his own:

> “Artoo?” C-3PO called. “Artoo, are you out here?”
>
> A few steps more and C-3PO could see the little astromech: he’d
> tangled his manipulator arm in the Senator’s clothing and was dragging
> her across the landing deck. “Artoo! Stop that this instant! You’ll
> damage her!”
>
> R2-D2’s dome swiveled to bring his photoreceptor to bear on the
> nervous protocol droid. WHAT EXACTLY DO YOU SUGGEST? it whistled.
>
> “Well … oh, all right. **We’ll do it together**.”
>
> <sub>*Revenge of the Sith*</sub>

The fact that he needed R2-D2’s help (and may even have been forced to help the droid drag her) suggests that he is not capable of carrying her by himself. But he’s clearly strong enough to make some appreciable contribution to carrying her.

In some Legends scripts, C-3PO carries Padme by himself (which would make him possibly a bit *stronger* than the average human), and the description is quite different from this scene. I don’t think any of that is canon anymore, though.

Besides, it fits with C-3PO’s general characterization: he’s a protocol droid, not a warrior. He moves slowly, and reacts poorly to fighting. It would have been a little odd if he had been built with normal human, let alone greater-than-human, strength.

Comment: Those blasters don't seem very heavy or have much recoil. I seem to recall Padme firing one one-handed in the same scene. Lifting the Jawas was probably a greater demonstration of strength.

Comment: @Null - Agreed (though Padme is actually trained in combat, so she might be pretty strong, and she might have a blaster pistol rather than whatever gun 3PO is carrying there). But that example was already given, and I thought it would be useful to show some other examples for additional support.

Comment: I thought she picked up a blaster rifle (carbine?) that was dropped by battle droid. It [looks about the same size](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/6/6f/Padme-SWE.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111001234615) as the one in your image of C-3PO.

Comment: I think she and C-3PO were both holding/firing an [E-5 blaster rifle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/E-5_blaster_rifle).

Comment: Might be an additional question there for how dexterous 3PO's fingers are